# js syntax : how to interpret this : return!!(exp) ;

Tags: javascript, syntax, return

working on a page basic example, I found this piece of code :

```
function hasGetUserMedia() {

return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);

}
```

and been astonished by : **return!!(exp)**

Can someone explain this '!!' ? is it for the line break ? or to avoid a return value ?

I could not find usage nor info about this kind of (weird) syntax

thanks !

Comment: ok sorry for the duplication and many thanks for precisions , forcing a return value type is both tricky and useful ! ... should have thought about it sooner ...

Answer (score 1):

The `!!` coerces the value into a boolean that represents whether the original value is "truthy" or "falsy".  For example:

```
!!"foo" // true
!!""    // false
```

Given that `!` is the negation operator, using it once will convert a value into a boolean that is the *opposite* of it's truthy/falsy value.  E.g.,

```
!"foo" // false
!""    // true
```

Adding another `!` negates the negation, resulting in a boolean that matches the truthy/falsy-ness of the original non-boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

The code below forces the expression to be converted to boolean.

```
function hasGetUserMedia() {

    return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);

}
```